# Cannot display the fields from a sub collection of a collection in flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I cannot display the fields from my sub collection.

This is my database in firebase.

[image][image]

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class FriendsList extends StatelessWidget {
  const FriendsList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text(
          'Friends List',
          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(currentUser!.uid)
            .collection('friends')
            .get(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text("Error");
          }

          final friends = snapshot.data!.docs;

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: friends.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final friend = friends[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(friend['first name'] + ' ' + friend['last name']),
                subtitle: Text(friend['email']),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[If I use the above code I am unable to display the details in the friends sub-collection of my users collection (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYaeS.png).[But if I give the document id manually, then I can see the list as expected.[This is when I give the doc id manually.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brBaL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWBEd.png)]

When I hardcode and give my document id in the current user field it shows the details as expected, but I want to retrieve it dynamically based on the current logged in user. I don't know what is the error in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since hard-coding the value works, it seems that `currentUser!.uid` is not the value you expect it to be.

I recommend debugging the problem by logging the `currentUser!.uid` value right before you use it. E.g.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  print(currentUser!.uid);
  ...
```

Then check the log output and compare it to the document ID/hard-coded value.

Comment: I did as you said and in the console the value that was printed is not the value of the document ID. I think this could be the issue since we need to give the document ID to go and actually retrieve the sub-collection and the field inside it, but also I don't know how I could give the document ID of the current user. I am really new to using flutter and firebase and I want to pursue a career in this field by creating applications. I appreciate your help. And also thank you Frank Sir for the response. Looking forward for your help in this regard.